# What is the best way to add greens to an omelette?

Tags: eggs, greens

I've started adding various greens (spinach and arugula) to my eggs and omelets. I've only tried a few ways:

- Add greens first to a hot pan with olive oil and butter. Add the eggs afterwards.
- Cook the eggs, etc. first then add the greens near the end of cooking.

Ideally, I'd like to preserve the freshness of the greens without it being a salad on top of my eggs.

Also, keeping the leaves whole doesn't seem to work out the best. Perhaps I should chop the greens before adding?

Comment: I cut up greens for an omelet because I find it _much_ easier to eat the result, and they also seem to be better distributed :)

Comment: It depends on the greens; if it is eaten raw, then add at the last moment possible to keep freshness; if usually eaten cooked; then cook it  in advance and add to the omelet.

Comment: related (but about pizza) : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36753/67

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the traditional french way would be that you add spices to eggs before cooking and stuff the omelette right before serving.

I've watched a few youtube videos on the matter and I like how Jacques Pepin explains the process. 
[Check it here.](http://youtu.be/57afEWn-QDg)

Jamie Olivers version is quite similar, he stuff omelette with cheese before he folds it. [Check it here.](http://youtu.be/AgHgbn_sVUw)

I've tried all version and I like them all. The main trick about an omelette is that you do not overcook the eggs. Everything else is personal preference I'd say, like whether to chop or no the greens.

Comment: +1 for personal preference. You can add the greens any way you like them, there is no right or wrong way.

Comment: If you are going to add greens, the best way to cook them is to cook your aromatics (onion, shallot, etc.) in a bit of fat, and when they are almost done you toss in your greens (like spinach). You give it a toss over heat for about 10 seconds, then remove from heat and let it finish.  You are basically wilting the greens, rather than cooking them through.

Answer (score 1):

I've been staying at a hotel where they offer made-to-order omelets during breakfast. The omelet maker uses your method #1. Note these are American-style folded omelets.

1. Add some (melted) butter to the pan.
2. Add filling ingredients, including whole spinach leaves, but not something like cheese.
3. Let everything fry for several seconds.
4. Add the egg and allow to cook.
5. Briefly flip to cook the top side of the egg, then flip back.
6. Add final ingredients like cheese, fold, and serve.

Answer (score 0):

Try “massaging” greens w/avocado oil until “silky.” Add to omelette. The oil inhibits production of water from veggies producing a more flavorful, attractive dish.
I use spinach, green onions, red mini bell, fresh ground black pepper and garlic powder.